# rxjs-marbles testing has no expectations

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-test, jasmine-marbles, rxjs-marbles

I use [rxjs-marbles](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-marbles) for testing observables in my Angular 7 app. But it looks like `m.expect` is not recognized by [jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io) as expectation.

I have following test:

```
it('should see expectations', marbles(m => {
  const source: Observable<Message> = m.hot('^a--b--c');
  m.expect(source).toBeObservable('-a--b--c');
}));
```

When I run it I get error in console:

```
ERROR: 'Spec 'FeatureFlagsService should see expectations' has no expectations.'
```

Also in browser output my test is prefixed with:

`SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS should see expectations`

Adding `expect(true).toBe(true);` fixes the issue but this is not really way I want to go.

How to register `m.expect` as a expectation for jasmine?

Comment: Did you import from rxjs-marbles/jasmine?  [rxjs-marbles/jasmine](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-marbles/blob/master/examples/jasmine/basic-spec.ts)

Comment: @dmcgrandle Yes, I use this import. I will try to create a stackblitz with reproduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually cased by the lib itself. I created an issue on github and it was solved quickly: https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-marbles/issues/51